# How to change column name according to another dataframe in R?

Tags: r

```
df1 <- data.frame(
    cola = c('1',NA,'c','1','1','e','1',NA,'c','d'),
    colb = c("A",NA,"C","D",'a','b','c','d','c','d'),
    colc = c('a',NA,'c','d','a',NA,'c',NA,'c','d'),stringsAsFactors = TRUE)

df2<-data.frame(name=c('cola','colc','colb'),
                altname=c('a','c','b'))

df1 %>% table %>% data.frame(.)
```

Result of above codes as:

```
   cola colb colc Freq
1     1    a    a    1
2     c    a    a    0
```

I want to change columns name of result based on `df2`(for example,change `colb` to `b` ),the expected result as:

```
      a    b    c Freq
1     1    a    a    1
2     c    a    a    0
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can just remove the substring with `rename_at`

```
library(stringr)
libraryr(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   table %>% 
   data.frame(.) %>%  
   rename_at(1:3, ~ str_remove(., "col"))
```

Or if it needs to be from 'df2'

```
df1 %>%
   table %>%
   data.frame(.) %>%
   rename_at(1:3, ~ setNames(as.character(df2$altname), df2$name)[.])
```

#### Update

If all the column names in 'df1' are not in key/val columns of 'df2', an option is

```
df1 %>%
   table %>%
    data.frame(.) %>%
    rename_at(1:3, ~ coalesce(setNames(as.character(df2$altname), df2$name)[.], .))
```

---

Or using base R

```
out <- df1 %>% table %>% data.frame(.)
names(out) <- sub("col", "", names(out))
```

if it needs to be based on a second dataset

```
name(out)[-4] <- df2$altname[match(names(out)[-4], df2$name)]
```

Or with `substr`

```
names(out) <- substring(names(out), 4)
```

Comment: the logic:change `df1` each column name,if there's corresponding one in `df2`

Comment: @kittygirl. If there is no corresponding match in df2, then what should be the output

Comment: if there's no corresponding, no change,output the same column name.

Comment: I tried `df1 %>% table %>% data.frame(.) %>% \`colnames<-\`(df2$altname[match(names(df1), df2$name)])`,the only unsatisfied thing is `Freq` has no match, become `NA`.Is there way to keep the same column name when no match?

Comment: @kittygirl. I used `coalesce`. It is working for me though and here I am using `rename_at` by reemoving the `Freq` column

Answer (score 0):

This was one of the more popular threads I landed at when researching the same issue.  More recent versions of `dplyr` have made this easier if you use a named vector and make use of the `any_of` function which makes it quite forgiving when you have column names which may be in df2 but not present in df1.

Using your case, you could:

```r
lookup <- setNames(as.character(df2$name), df2$altname)
df1 %>% 
  rename(any_of(lookup)) %>% 
  table %>% 
  data.frame(.)
```

Or as an embedded one-liner:

```r
df1 %>% 
  rename(any_of(setNames(as.character(df2$name), df2$altname))) %>% 
  table %>% 
  data.frame(.)
```

Or if you want to eschew the `setNames` process, there's a nice `deframe` function in `tibble` that converts the first two columns of a dataframe to a named vector (and ignores the rest), but your columns in df2 would be the wrong way round (oldname, newname).

References:

- https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/rename.html
- https://tibble.tidyverse.org/reference/enframe.html